# Selenium loses control of the browser after running Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In Selenium, when I run commands, like

```
document.evaluate("My Xpath", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null)
```

the WebDriver loses control of the browser. Nothing past that Javascript execution runs and the test will always fail.

I suppose that it's related to returning an element, but I've found nothing about it anywhere.

edit:

The relevant code

```
public CustomPage Login(string username, string password) 
{
    SendKeys(username, EmailSlot);
    SendKeys(password, PasswordSlot);
    LoginButton.Click();
    while True 
    {
        try 
        {
            if ((driver as IJavaScriptExecutor).ExecuteScript("document.evaluate(\"//a[text() = 'log out'\", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue") != null) break;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        { }
    }
    return CustomPage(driver);
}
```

Comment: can we see the surrounding, and relevant C# code ?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are running the XPath through JavaScript as opposed through Selenium's own native methods?

Comment: @Arran The current code we have works sporadically which uses Selenium's XPath methods. I'm trying to see if there's a better solution that works more than once in a while.

Comment: @Brad, OK, my suggestion would be to figure out why it's works sometimes and fails other times, and not to bypass Selenium altogether. Nonetheless, you must give Selenium a little nudge when executing JS that you expect to return *something*, so make it `return document.evaluate(\"//a[text() = 'log out'\", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue` as a first try. If the XPath gives you a result, Selenium should return it as an `IWebElement`.